# Factory Girl has_one Association create Confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I have following two models:

**Category**

```
category_name
```

**Skill** (has_one: category)

```
skill_name
skill_desc
category_id
```

my confusion is that, how can i made simple Factory Girl objects for category and skill ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :category do
          category_name 'Name'              
      end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :skill do
          skill_name 'Name'  
          skill_desc 'Desc'
          category { create(:category) }            
      end
end
```

I'd recommend looking into the Faker gem so that you can get unique text injected into your models.  This will be helpful once add any unique validations.

Also, IMO, it is redundant to name pre-pend column names with the name of the table.

Just to be clear, because your skill table has the category foreign key, it is considered to "belong_to category" in rails terminology, not "has one".

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create different factories for category and skill in the following way:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
    category_name 'Name'              
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :skill do
    skill_name 'Name'  
    skill_desc 'Desc'
    category             
  end
end
```

You don't need to write `category { create(:category) }` unless you want to specify the build strategy or change category attributes. For more information about [factory girl associations read this article](https://kolosek.com/factory-girl-associations).